# How to redirect to custom URL user clicked on after authenticating with passport.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to authenticate users by SSO. The frontend is Angular8.

On the app's initial load, the app.component will check if the req.user object exists on the backend. If not, it redirect's to the auth/login route for passport authentication. Currently, the successRedirect is set to '/'.

The problem/question is that our app emails a URL for a user to view a specific dataset. For a user that clicks this link, we'd like the login redirect to send them to the original link they clicked on after the SSO logs them in.

Currently, if the user is not logged into the app when entering a URL, it redirects to the base URL '/'.

**Angular App Component Check Login Method**

```
 async checkLogin() {
        let cameFromUrl = this.location.path();

        //skip user check if on localhost
        if (window.location.href.includes('localhost')) {
            return this.router.navigateByUrl(cameFromUrl)
        }

        //load the current user
        const user = <IUser>await this.userService
            .getUser()
            .toPromise()

        //if user not logged in redirect to login page otherwise to home
        if (user.error) {
            window.location.href = 'api/auth/login'
        } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(cameFromUrl)
        }
    }
```

**Authentication Route in Express**

```
    .get('/login', passport.authenticate('oauth2', { successRedirect: '/' }))
    .get('/callback', passport.authenticate('oauth2'), (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/')
    })
    .get('/user', validateUser, async (req, res) => {

        if (req.user) {
            res.json({
                error: false,
                result: req.user,
            })
        } else {
            res.json({
                error: true,
                result: 'User not logged in',
            })
        }
    })
```

I've tried adding (req, res) to the login route and redirecting to the req.path, but this didn't work.

**Example of what I've tried (snippets from code above)**

```
// Frontend
        let cameFromUrl = this.location.path();
        if (user.error) {
            window.location.href = `api/auth/login/${cameFromUrl}`
        } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(cameFromUrl)
        }

// Express Backend
        .get('/login/:cameFromUrl', passport.authenticate('oauth2', (req,res) => { res.redirect(`/${req.params.cameFromUrl}`) }))
```

The above resulting in the app constantly redirecting to api/login/auth over and over and over again.

If the user is trying to access the path '/data/1', the end result is that they are redirecting to that URL rather than the base URL '/' after successful authentication.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your client and API server are at the same host? (i.e. https://www.some-app.com)

Comment: Yes, they're at the same host